# How is a root directory used for resolution of absolute pathnames?

Tags: filenames, chroot

APUE says

> Each  process  also  has  a  root  directory  that  is  used  for  resolution  of  absolute  pathnames.
>   This root directory can be changed with the chroot function.

I thought only relative pathnames need resolution. So I was wondering

- what does resolution of absolute pathnames mean?
- how does `chroot` use a root directory for resolution of absolute pathnames? 
  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pathnames need resolution. 
Obviously, processes pass pathnames to the kernel
as arguments to system calls like:

- `creat` or `open`,
- `link` or `rename`,
- `unlink` or `rmdir`,
- `chmod` or `chown`,
- `chdir` or `chroot`,
- `execve`,

etc. 
Consider a pathname that looks something like

> …  `a`  `/`  `b`  `/`  `c`

The way the kernel interprets this is:

> Starting (somewhere in the filesystem),
>   Look for a directory called `a`<sup>1</sup>.
>       If not found, return an error.
>       If found, then search that directory for a subdirectory called `b`.
>           If not found, return an error.
>           If found, then search that directory for directory entry called `c`<sup>2</sup>.
>               If not found, return an error<sup>3</sup>.
>               If found, return that inode.

Notice the obfuscation at the beginning of the pathname,
and in the first line of the algorithm. 
It’s simple: if the pathname begins with a slash
(i.e., it’s an “absolute pathname”, e.g., `/a/b/c`),
the search begins at the process’s root directory,
and if the pathname begins with anything else
(i.e., it’s a relative pathname, e.g., `a/b/c`),
the search begins at the process’s current working directory.

---

You may ask “How is this achieved?” 
Well, of course,
the kernel maintains a lot of information about each process, including

- PID, PPID, and various process group identifiers,
- real, effective, and saved UID and GID, and supplementary GID list,
- open files,
- signal dispositions,

and more. 
I left out many things because they’re irrelevant to this question. 
I left out environment variables because they’re not maintained by the kernel;
they’re maintained by user-space programs. 
All the kernel does is support a mechanism
for passing environment variables from one program to another through `execve`.

Two things I left out of the above list for dramatic purposes are:

- process’s root directory, and
- current working directory

These are pointers to inodes. 
I expect everybody who has gotten this far
understands how the process’s current working directory is set —
the process calls `chdir`, passing it a pathname as an argument;
the kernel interprets the pathname (resolves it to an inode)
following the procedure described above,
and, upon success, sets the current directory pointer to point to that inode.

The process’s root directory is set the same way,
except with the `chroot` system call.

(Note that, in either case, if the pathname argument begins with `/`,
the pathname resolution starts at the process’s root directory
*in effect when the system call is invoked*. )

Some examples:

- If your current directory is `/home/tim`
  (and your process root directory is the filesystem root), then

  - if you access `/etc/services`, you will get `/etc/services`,
  - if you access `.bashrc`, you will get `/home/tim/.bashrc`.
- If you do `chroot /filesystem/tim`
  (assuming that there is a directory by that name, and you have access to it,
  and you have the necessary privilege to `chroot`), then

  - if you access `/etc/services`, you will get `/filesystem/tim/etc/services`,
  - if you access `/`, you will get `/filesystem/tim`, so
  - if you `chroot /`, nothing will change;
  - if you `chroot /filesystem/john`,
    it will try to `chroot` to `/filesystem/tim/filesystem/john`.

Since the root directory and the current directory
are stored as pointers to inodes, the system doesn’t need to “locate” them.
__________
<sup>1</sup> i.e., look for a directory entry that points to an inode whose mode indicates that it is a directory, i.e., `(i_mode & IFMT) == IFDIR`.

<sup>2</sup> for the last segment of the pathname,
it doesn’t care what type of file it is;
it could be a directory, a plain file, a named pipe,
a symbolic link, a device, … whatever.
<sup>3</sup> if the last segment of the pathname is not found,
but the system call is `creat(file, mode)`
or (equivalently) `open(file, O_CREAT, mode)`,
or anything else than can create a directory entry,

the operation will not fail.

Comment: I know that this question already has an accepted answer.  But some of the information content of that answer lies in the comments (rather than in the body of the answer), and, IMO, even the aggregate answer (including the comments) is unclear and borderline incomplete.  That’s why I’m adding this answer.

Answer (score 2):

When the kernel resolves e.g. `/usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz` to an inode, it will have to start from the root `/`, and work its way down to `cat.1.gz`. In the case of a relative pathname, it needs only look up the file in the current directory.

Maybe you were thinking of how to get the absolute path to the current working directory? To determine the path, you will have to work your way from the current directory, through all the intermediate directories up to the root. (But note that the kernel does not do this when given a relative path to a file, e.g. as a parameter to the `open` syscall.)

Comment: Thanks. My questions is that **given an absolute pathname**, what does it mean by resolution of the absolute pathname, and how a root directory is used for the resolution?

Comment: Resolving a pathname means locating a file or directory in a filesystem, based on its name. If the path is absolute (begins with a slash), it means the kernel will have to first locate the root directory, and in that directory locate the next component (`usr` in my example) by seaching the root directory. The process is repeated for all path components, and the result is the inode of the wanted file or directory (`cat.1.1gz` in the example). If the path is not absolute (i.e. it does not begin with a slash), then the search is similar, but instead starts from the current directory.

Comment: How does `chroot` use root directory for resolution of absolute pathnames?

Comment: `chroot` changes the root directory of the process, i.e. the directory seen as `/`. When you change the root e.g. with `chroot("/var/vmroots/vm1")`, then what was `/var/vmroots/vm1/usr` can now be found using the path `/usr`. What is outside the new root is now inaccessible to the chrooted process. Chroot affects path resolution only in that resolution now begins at the new root.

Comment: How does `chroot` achieve that? Does `chroot` create a symlink named `/` linking to `/var/vmroots/vm1`?  If yes, does the symlink override the original `/`?

Comment: No, it is done internally in the kernel.